# Scientific committee member "in", "of", or "for" the contest?

Tags: prepositions

Which of the sentences below is the correct one, and what is the general rule?

1. I am a scientific committee member in CONTEST_NAME
2. I am a scientific committee member of CONTEST_NAME
3. I am a scientific committee member for CONTEST_NAME

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second is unclear, but the first and third example use valid English but imply different things:

- "I am a scientific committee member in CONTEST_NAME," implies your group is **participating in** the contest, though that seems an unlikely scenario.
- "I am a scientific committee member for CONTEST_NAME," implies your group is **supervising or advising** the contest.